# static const member inizialitazion in template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, constants

In file SomeClass.h

```
#ifndef SOME_CLASS_H_
#define SOME_CLASS_H_

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <class T, class P>
class SomeClass
{
      public:
            SomeClass();
            void SomeMethod();

      protected: 
              typedef unsigned int heapPosition;
              heapPosition someVariable;


      private:                
              static const heapPosition NULLPOSITION;
};

template <class T, class P>
const typename SomeClass<T,P>::heapPosition SomeClass<T,P>::NULLPOSITION = -1;

template <class T, class P>
SomeClass<T,P>::SomeClass(){}

template <class T, class P>
void SomeClass<T,P>::SomeMethod()
{
    someVariable=NULLPOSITION;
    cout<<"NULLPOSITION:"<<NULLPOSITION<<endl;
}

#endif
```

In file main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "SomeClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SomeClass<int,int> someClass;

    someClass.SomeMethod();

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Basically I have a templated class with a static const member `(NULLPOSITION)`.
I have tried inizialitazion of the of the class, both outside class definition and inline
as in

```
static const heapPosition NULLPOSITION=-1;
```

when declaring the member.

However, in both cases, when I reference in `SomeMethod`its values is some random value - i.e. it has not been initialized.

I have done this type of thing many other times, and I have never had this type of problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Can somebody please help me? Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Thanks,
Gerald Celente

Comment: Please use the preview to edit your post to make it look sane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is a random value? You have declared your `NULLPOSITION` as `unsigned`, so assigning it `-1` will cause `cout.operator<<` (invoked in `unsigned` overload) to print some large value (`4294967295` for 32bit `int`)

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
template <class T, class P>
const typename SomeClass<T, P>::heapPosition SomeClass<T, P>::NULLPOSITION = -1;
```

Or just:

```
template <class T, class P>
const unsigned int SomeClass<T, P>::NULLPOSITION = -1;
```

(And this needs to go into the header file.)

However, even better is to add the initializer to the class definition:

```
private:
    static const heapPosition NULLPOSITION = -1;
```

That way you might get away entirely without defining the variable (as long as it isn't odr-used.)

Comment: The only difference your code and the OP's code have is a space before `P>`. I seriously doubt it is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are declaring `NULLPOSITION` as `unsigned int` and assigning it `-1`